# Various way to send data to the web server

Tags: php, python, web-services, http

**Client Environment :** Windows XP , Internet connection Available, PHP Not installed.

**Server Environment :** CentOS , Internet connection Available, PHP , MYsql installed.

Data are stored in files at client machine , suggest better ways to send data fetched from the file to the server. Normally i would be using HTTP request using Curl to send the data to the server but client machine doesnt have php installed.

What all are the ways to send data to the server and the comparisons?

Note: In client machine the data are to be taken from the file and to be sent in background as a daemon.

Comment: You can still use Curl without PHP from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to install some sort of software on the client machine to make the data available to the server, there is really no other simple way that I can think of other than writing a web app to upload the files (which may not be practical, and certainly requires manual labor).

Otherwise, you could setup an sFTP server (or something that accomplishes the same thing) on the client machine, and [use PHP to connect to the sFTP service](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php) on the client machine.